# Why can't I scan %c character?

Tags: c, scanf

It is not scanning character after string is scanned successfully while c programming.

```
char s[10],c;
scanf("%s",s);
scanf("%c",&c);
printf("%s\n",s);
printf("%c",c);
```

Comment: What happens? What do you expect? What do you see instead? What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: This question is asked daily, and given the amount of problems it gives to newbies, it should be taken seriously. At least provide and answer or a close-duplicate vote.

Comment: Maybe, the compiler didn't like what you wrote. That's why, it didn't scan.

Comment: You should do `printf("Decimal value of c is %d", (int) c);` to see what you actually got.

Comment: try `scanf("%s %c", s, &c);`

Comment: As a side note, `scanf("%s", s);` without a width specifier is a security problem. Always specify the maximum length of the string that should be scanned. This continues to be one of the top ten security problems, year in, year out, decade after decade.

Answer (score 4):

`scanf` manual:

> specifier c:
>
> Matches a sequence of characters whose length is specified by the maximum
>   field  width (default 1); the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and
>   there must be enough room for all the  characters  (no  terminating  null
>   byte is added).  *The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed.  To
>   skip white space first, use an explicit space in the format.*

So, change format to `" %c"`.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
char s[10],c;
scanf("%s",s);
scanf("%c",&c);
printf("%s\n",s);
printf("%c",c);
```

will not work as intended, because when you use the `scanf("%s",s);` you will enter a string from keyboard then press enter. That `scanf("%s",s);` will store the string in `s` from the buffer, but will let the `enter` or more precisely `\n` in the buffer. The next `scanf("%c",&c);` will read that `\n`, because it's 1 character long and will store it in `c`. But when you print it you will see nothing because it's just a new line. To prevent all of this change the second `scanf("%c",&c);` with `scanf(" %c",&c);` leaving a space for the `\n`.

Hope this helps you understand what's happening.

Comment: "But when you print it you will see nothing because it's just a new line" - OP won't see nothing, OP will see a new line.

Answer (score 0):

After typing the characters for string 's' you type a enter '\n' the next scan for character captures the new line and  prints it . what you can do is, capture that new line '\n'. Put the scanf("%c",&c);
one more time it will work.

```
char s[10],c;
`scanf("%s",s);`
`scanf("%c",&c);`
`scanf("%c",&c)`
`printf("%s\n",s);`
`printf("%c",c);`
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'enter' or '\n' from the end of your previously scanned string is what gets scanned by your scanf("%c", &c)

try putting a dummy getchar() after your scanf("%s",s)

```
scanf("%s",s);
getchar();
scanf("%c",&c);
printf("%s\n",s);
printf("%c",c);
```

or, leave a space before your format specifier in scanf("%c",c) and make it scanf(" %c",c)

```
scanf("%s",s);
scanf(" %c",&c);
printf("%s\n",s);
printf("%c",c);
```

in both cases, the dummy getchar() and the extra whitespace before %c will take care of your unwanted '\n' character